# Spring Batch Xml Item Read

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-batch

I'm working with Spring Batch.
I think I already know how I can parse good-looking xml and binding object.

And I stuck with this problem.

```xml
<parent>
  <child>
    <key name="xxx">
      <value>val</value>
    </key>
    <key name="yyy">
      <value>val</value>
    </key>
  </child>
</parent>
```

How can I parse xml items for above xml to children defined like this?

```java
class Child {

    private String xxx;
    private String yyy;
}
```

I know how I can parse when it looks like this.

```xml
<parent>
  <child>
    <xxx>val</xxx>
    <yyy>val</yyy>
  </child>
</parent>
```

Is there any XPath like mappings with Spring-Batch's XML item reader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [Jaxb2Unmarshaller](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/oxm/jaxb/Jaxb2Marshaller.html).
Check aroudn for a jaxb solution: it's full around the net.
In the worst case I remember you can write your own node parser and manage this form of your `child` tag.
I'm sorry but I can't add code because I'm not at work. 
Hope can be help